# how to put multiple jquery dataTables in one page?

Tags: jquery, datatables

I want to use jquery dataTables to show something.

It works well when i just put one dataTable in one page, then i add one more, but they occupied almost the same position, and one of them doesn't work well.

Do you know how to deal with that?

Answer (score 13):

```html
<table id="table1" class="display"> </table>
<table id="table2" class="display"> </table>
<table id="table3" class="display"> </table>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('table.display').DataTable();
} );
```

All three tables will be displayed as long as you give the right class

<-- You wrote dataTable instead of DataTable-->

Answer (score 7):

It is possible with server side processing. I have it working in a number of locations in my application. You just need to follow the example code for the server side processing multiple times...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').dataTable( {
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bServerSide": true,
        "sAjaxSource": "../examples_support/server_processing.php"
    } );
} );
```

replacing `#example` with `#id-of-your-table` and `"sAjaxSource": "../examples_support/server_processing.php"` with `"sAjaxSource": "url/to/your/server/side/script"`.

My guess is that you used the `.dataTable` selector from the multiple tables example. Which will apply the same setup to all tables with the dataTable class.

Answer (score 5):

I'm late to the party but here's the method I ended up using to solve the problem you describe...

```
$('.testDataTable').each(function() {
        var dataSource = $(this).attr("data-ajaxsource");
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bServerSide": true,
        "sAjaxSource": dataSource
    });
});
```

You're essentially iterating through your DataTable instances and adding the source set by a data attribute. If you're not familiar with data attributes, they're simply tags applied to an element...

```
<div id="testDataTable" data-ajaxsource="http://myserver.com/json"></div>
```

**Alternatively**, If you don't want to use the HTML5 data attributes, you could use a hidden field within the parent which could be read directly into the sAjaxSource...

```
$('.testDataTable').each(function() {
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bServerSide": true,
        "sAjaxSource": $(this).children('childElement').html()
    });
});
```

Comment: i like ur idea and tryed it out, i found out that it works better without "bProcessing": true, "bServerSide": true,

Answer (score 2):

If you have multiple datatables on the single page - check if you are using the following from the examples

```
"fnServerData": fnDataTablesPipeline
```

this caches the data from the first call; if the second datatable uses the same function it will see that data has already been fetched and not make the ajax call to retrieve its data. and so you will not receive data to your second(nth) datatable.

Answer (score 2):

select selector by class
i have two or more table and i want init all off theme with one config
you can set for all table a class such as:

```
<table class="mytable">
<table class="mytable">
...
...
...
```

and init theme such as:

```
    $('.mytable').DataTable({
        order: [[0, "desc"]],
        language: {
            "lengthMenu": "نمایش  _MENU_ ردیف در هر صفحه",
            "zeroRecords": "متاسفیم هیچ کاربری مطابق با اطلاعات درخواست شده یافت نشد",
            "info": "نمایش برگه _PAGE_ از  _PAGES_  از _TOTAL_  کاربر",
            "infoEmpty": "هیچ اطلاعاتی یافت نشد",
            "infoFiltered": "(فیلتر شده از _MAX_ کاربر)",
            "search": "جستجو:",
            "paginate": {
                "first": "نخست",
                "last": "آخرین",
                "next": "بعدی",
                "previous": "قبلی"
            },
        },
    })
```

Answer (score 2):

This answered is inspired from(@TinkeringTurtle) one of the answers in this thread.

```
let dt_columns = ["columns for table1", "columns for table2", "etc"];
let tables = [];
$('.table').each(function(i, el) {
    var dataSource = $(this).attr("data-ajaxsource");
    var columns = dt_columns[i];
     tables[i] = $(this).DataTable({
      "processing": true,
      "serverSide": true,
      "ajax": {
          "url": dataSource,
          "type": "POST",
          "data":{
            "month": function(){return $("#select_month").val()},
            "year": function(){return $("#select_year").val()},
          }
      },
      "columns": columns
    });
});
/* reload datatable */
$("#select_month, #select_year").change(function(){
  console.log(tables);
  tables.forEach(function(el, i){
    el.ajax.reload();
  });
});
```

Comment: managing dataTables inside an array like you have done : let tables = [ ] ... is not working for me

Comment: I always get the last instance of dataTable registred in the array tables[].. however I think it will be better to use `new $.fn.dataTable.Api("#tableSelector")` to manage/get each instance of dataTable, than using an array to store them.

Comment: This helped me like you have no idea. Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

Still working on it... but this could be helpful

```
<div class="col-md-12">
          <!-- Custom Tabs -->
          <div class="nav-tabs-custom">
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
              <li class="active"><a href="#tab_1" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="true">Web Design and Development</a></li>
              <li class=""><a href="#tab_2" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="false">Domain Registration</a></li>
              <li class=""><a href="#tab_3" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="false">Cloud Computing Services</a></li>
              <li class=""><a href="#tab_4" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="false">Android application Development</a></li>
              <li class=""><a href="#tab_5" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="false">Web Hosting</a></li>
              <li class=""><a href="#tab_6" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="false">SEO and Online Marketing</a></li>
              <li class="pull-right"><a href="#" class="text-muted"><i class="fa fa-gear"></i></a></li>
            </ul>
            <div class="tab-content">
              <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab_1">
                <b>Web Deign and development hires:</b>




                <table class="table" id="webdesignTable">                   
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>S.no</th>
                            <th>Order By</th>                                                   
                            <th>Phone</th>
                            <th>Email</th>
                            <th>Message</th>
                            <th>Date</th>                                               
                            <th>Status</th>
                            <th>Options</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                </table>



              </div>
              <!-- /.tab-pane -->
              <div class="tab-pane" id="tab_2">
              <b>Domain Registration</b>


              <table class="table" id="domainregistrationTable">                    
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>S.no</th>
                            <th>Order By</th>                                                   
                            <th>Phone</th>
                            <th>Email</th>
                            <th>Message</th>
                            <th>Date</th>                                               
                            <th>Status</th>
                            <th>Options</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                </table>



              </div>
              <!-- /.tab-pane -->
              <div class="tab-pane" id="tab_3">
               <b>Cloud Computing</b>


              <table class="table" id="cloudcomputingTable">                    
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>S.no</th>
                            <th>Order By</th>                                                   
                            <th>Phone</th>
                            <th>Email</th>
                            <th>Message</th>
                            <th>Date</th>                                               
                            <th>Status</th>
                            <th>Options</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                </table>
              </div>
              <!-- /.tab-pane -->

              <!-- /.tab-pane -->
              <div class="tab-pane" id="tab_4">
               <b>Android application Development</b>


              <table class="table" id="androidappTable">                    
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>S.no</th>
                            <th>Order By</th>                                                   
                            <th>Phone</th>
                            <th>Email</th>
                            <th>Message</th>
                            <th>Date</th>                                               
                            <th>Status</th>
                            <th>Options</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                </table>
              </div>
              <!-- /.tab-pane -->

              <!-- /.tab-pane -->
              <div class="tab-pane" id="tab_5">
               <b>Web Hosting</b>


              <table class="table" id="webhostingTable">                    
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>S.no</th>
                            <th>Order By</th>                                                   
                            <th>Phone</th>
                            <th>Email</th>
                            <th>Message</th>
                            <th>Date</th>                                               
                            <th>Status</th>
                            <th>Options</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                </table>
              </div>
              <!-- /.tab-pane -->

              <!-- /.tab-pane -->
              <div class="tab-pane" id="tab_6">
               <b>SEO and Online Marketing</b>


              <table class="table" id="seoTable">                   
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>S.no</th>
                            <th>Order By</th>                                                   
                            <th>Phone</th>
                            <th>Email</th>
                            <th>Message</th>
                            <th>Date</th>                                               
                            <th>Status</th>
                            <th>Options</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                </table>
              </div>
              <!-- /.tab-pane -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.tab-content -->
          </div>
          <!-- nav-tabs-custom -->
        </div>
```

The script

```
// global the manage tables 
var manageMemberTable;
//var tbl1 = $('#webdesignTable').DataTable( );

$(document).ready(function() {

     $('table.display').dataTable(); //focus here

    manageMemberTable = $("#webdesignTable").DataTable({
        "ajax": "webdesign_action/retrieve.php", //get data for your tables
        "order": []
    });

    domainregistrationTable = $("#domainregistrationTable").DataTable({
        "ajax": "domainregistration_action/retrieve.php", //get data for your tables
        "order": []
    });
//It continues
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML such as:

```
<table id="Table01" class="table"></table>
<table id="Table02" class="table"></table>
<table id="Table03" class="table"></table>
<table id="Table04" class="table"></table>
```

script such as:

```
table01 = $("#Table01").DataTable({/* to do somthing... */});
table02 = $("#Table02").DataTable({/* to do somthing... */});
table03 = $("#Table03").DataTable({/* to do somthing... */});
table04 = $("#Table04").DataTable({/* to do somthing... */});
```