# Datatables with multiple tables on one page

Tags: javascript, datatables

I'm looking on the datatables.net website for some clarification or documentation rather about what to do if you have more than 1 table on a single page and want to handle each one differently.

I tried the obvious. Assigning each to a different id and then performing the code for each in my js but for some reason its not allowing it. I'm not getting an error but datatables itself breaks and doesn't perform anything.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var oTable = $('#inbox').dataTable( {
    "bAutoWidth": false, 
    "aoColumnDefs": [
        { "bSortable": false, "aTargets": [ 0, -1 ] },
        { "sWidth": "20px", "aTargets": [ 0, -1 ] },
        { "sWidth": "100px", "aTargets": [ 1 ] },
        { "sWidth": "150px", "aTargets": [ 3 ] }
    ]
} );

var oTable = $('#sent').dataTable( {
    "bAutoWidth": false, 
    "aoColumnDefs": [
        { "bSortable": false, "aTargets": [ 0, -1 ] },
        { "sWidth": "20px", "aTargets": [ 0, -1 ] },
        { "sWidth": "100px", "aTargets": [ 1 ] },
        { "sWidth": "150px", "aTargets": [ 3 ] }
    ]
} );

});
```

**UPDATE**

http://pastebin.com/4d3kPmk0

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var oTable = $('.dataTable').dataTable( {
    "bAutoWidth": false, 
    "aoColumnDefs": [
        { "bSortable": false, "aTargets": [ 0, -1 ] },
        { "sWidth": "20px", "aTargets": [ 0, -1 ] },
        { "sWidth": "100px", "aTargets": [ 1 ] },
        { "sWidth": "150px", "aTargets": [ 3 ] }
    ]
} );

});

$(window).load(function(){
/*
 * Tabs
 */
$('#tab-panel-1').createTabs();
});
```

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1790065/how-to-put-multiple-jquery-datatables-in-one-page

Comment: Thank you. I must have looked everyone and couldn't find something good.

Comment: For some reason when I apply a class of dataTable to both tables and instead use ('.dataTable).dataTabl({ ... it still isn't functioning correctly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are redeclaring the same variable.

```
var oTable = $('#inbox').dataTable({ /* ... */ });

var oTable = $('#sent').dataTable({ /* ... */ });
```

The "oTable" part of this is just what Allan (the author) happens to use in his examples to fit in with his conventions. The lowercase 'o' refers to something that's an object, and it's a table. But you can use whatever name you want.

You had the right idea, but you need to use:

```
var inboxTable = $('#inbox').dataTable({ /* ... */ });

var sentTable = $('#sent').dataTable({ /* ... */  });
```

And then if you're following his other examples on the site, you just substitute your own variable name for "oTable".

Live sample: http://live.datatables.net/amixis/edit#javascript,html

---

[update]

I should mention that recently I'm storing multiple tables in a nested object; I have a polling mechanism that iterates over particular arrays of tables (and not others), so the sample object looks something like this:

```
var oTables = {
  "polling" : [
    $('#someTable').dataTable(opts),
    $('#anotherTable').dataTable(opts)
  ],
  "nonpolling" : [
    $('#staticTable').dataTable(opts)
  ]
};
```

The net result is still the same. But I can now call setTimeouts over my array of polling table objects:

```
if(someBoolean) {
  for(var i=0; i < oTables.polling.length; i++) {
    setTimeout(pollingFunction, 5000)
  }
}
```

(highly simplified)

Comment: I ran in other issue which can be solved by making sure the oaColumn variable is named differently for different tables.