# jQuery DataTables filter multiple tables

Tags: jquery, datatable, datatables, filtering

I am using jQuery DataTables in some of my HTML tables. Well, I have a page where I list severral tables and I have to filter all of them by the same filters. In the case is a date range that I customized.

All of the tables use the same css class to construct the dataTable and the search by date-range i did at

```
$.fn.dataTableExt.afnFiltering.push(fn).
```

I also have another search by text, using

```
$('.dataTable').dataTable().fnFilter(
    searchVal,
    4,
    false,
    true
);
```

and this one is also working in only one table, not in them all as I was expecting to be.

Thanks,

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to put multiple jquery dataTables in one page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1790065/how-to-put-multiple-jquery-datatables-in-one-page)

Comment: It's not duplicate, OP is asking for custom filters working in each instance of DataTables with a isolated scope

Answer (score 1):

did you notice this 
**Range filtering (dates)**

*Show details   Filter a column on a specific date range. **Note that you will likely need to change the id's** on the inputs and the columns in which the start and end date exist.*

```
$.fn.dataTableExt.afnFiltering.push(
function( oSettings, aData, iDataIndex ) {
    var iFini = document.getElementById('fini').value;
    var iFfin = document.getElementById('ffin').value;
    var iStartDateCol = 6;
    var iEndDateCol = 7;

    iFini=iFini.substring(6,10) + iFini.substring(3,5)+ iFini.substring(0,2)
    iFfin=iFfin.substring(6,10) + iFfin.substring(3,5)+ iFfin.substring(0,2)       

    var datofini=aData[iStartDateCol].substring(6,10) + aData[iStartDateCol].substring(3,5)+ aData[iStartDateCol].substring(0,2);
    var datoffin=aData[iEndDateCol].substring(6,10) + aData[iEndDateCol].substring(3,5)+ aData[iEndDateCol].substring(0,2);

    if ( iFini == "" && iFfin == "" )
    {
        return true;
    }
    else if ( iFini <= datofini && iFfin == "")
    {
        return true;
    }
    else if ( iFfin >= datoffin && iFini == "")
    {
        return true;
    }
    else if (iFini <= datofini && iFfin >= datoffin)
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
});
```

also

**Range filtering (numbers)** 
Filter a specific numeric column on the value being between two given numbers. **Note that you will likely need to change the id's** on the *inputs* and the *column* in which the **numeric value** is given.

Comment: Hi, thanks for this. Well, it's pretty much what I did, and it will still work on only one table, not in a range. Upvote because it works, but still will not solve my problem. As I saw up there in a comment, seems that I can do this in a .each() and will work. I'm gooing to test this right now. Thanks again!