# How can I perform table specific filtering for multiple datatables in a single page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, filtering, datatables

I have 4 datatables in a a single page out of which three use the `$.fn.dataTableExt.afnFiltering.push` method of the filter API. My problem is that the filtering gets applied to all the tables present in the page at the same time.I tried destroying the existing tables before creating new ones but still I have had no luck.

Comment: How are you initializing the tables?

Comment: @KevinB a call like this $("#myTable").dataTable();

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13114548/jquery-datatables-filter-multiple-tables and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1790065/how-to-put-multiple-jquery-datatables-in-one-page